# I need help identifying this font

Tags: font-identification

need some help identifying this font, I've tried online id but no luck...
thanks

here:
[image]

Comment: try out this website to find fonts
https://www.myfonts.com/WhatTheFont/
...hint: the actual match does not appear, but one of the font family does so you have to investigate the rest of the font pack.

Answer (score 1):

Two close matches [On Stage font](http://www.myfonts.com/fonts/softmaker/on-stage-serial/)

[image]

OR

[RagTime font](http://www.myfonts.com/fonts/ef-typeshop/ragtime/) -

[image]